# How to build HTML reports from Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rubygems, testunit

I am using Selenium Webdriver + Test::Unit test runner for Ruby.
Ultimately, I want to output the testing results to HTML page. Could you advise me how to do it?
Seems like RSpec testing library has this functionality, but what about Test::Unit?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try RCov (https://github.com/relevance/rcov) or SimpleCov (https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov), they offer test coverage outputs in HTML. I'm aware this is not what you're looking for, but they could help you ;)

cheers,

A.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for the hint. I'll consider to use RCov for the Ruby code coverage by Selenium. Still Im looking for the way to get the results of Test::Unit in a nice HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering this question very late.

I have recently started developing [a gem to emit HTML reports from Test::Unit ruby](https://github.com/tamizhgeek/test-unit-runner-html). Please have a look and comment. That might be useful for any of your future projects.